io.cucumber.testng.UndefinedStepException: The step 'the user is on login page' and 3 other step(s) are undefined
I was doing a course on cucumber and was following along but i got struck right here in that project too,so I created this new project to check if this works but no its still the same.
I don't know why its not working as it should, path is correct, I checked the dependencies,I double checked the features file too.

Feature: User Login

  Scenario: User should be able to login with valid credentials
    Given the user is on login page
    When the user enters valid credentials
    And click on submit button
    Then verify login status


package stepDefs;

import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class Steps {

    @Given("the user is on login page")
    public void the_user_is_on_login_page() {
        System.out.println("login page");
    }

    @When("the user enters valid credentials")
    public void the_user_enters_valid_credentials() {
        System.out.println("entered stuff");
    }

    @And("click on submit button")
    public void click_on_submit_button() {
        System.out.println("clicking");
    }

    @Then("verify login status")
    public void verify_login_status() {
        System.out.println("pls work");
    }
}


package runners;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources",glue = {"runners.run"})

public class run extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {


}


this is the error I am getting:
io.cucumber.testng.UndefinedStepException: The step 'the user is on login page' and 3 other step(s) are undefined.
You can implement these steps using the snippet(s) below:

@Given("the user is on login page")
public void the_user_is_on_login_page() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
@When("the user enters valid credentials")
public void the_user_enters_valid_credentials() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
@When("click on submit button")
public void click_on_submit_button() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
@Then("verify login status")
public void verify_login_status() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}


    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.TestCaseResultObserver.assertTestCasePassed(TestCaseResultObserver.java:69)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestCaseResultObserver.assertTestCasePassed(TestCaseResultObserver.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.lambda$runScenario$1(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:136)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:136)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:136)
    at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:132)
    at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.runScenario(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:141)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:686)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:230)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:992)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:203)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:154)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:134)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:739)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:614)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:421)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:413)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:373)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1274)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1112)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1079)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:65)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)



after a lots of searching 'glue = {"runners.run"}' was the error,it was supposed to be just 'glue = {"runners"}'. (just the package name)
